# Getting fontInfo from monaco-editor instance?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to get the `typicalFullwidthCharacterWidth` property which is available in the `FontInfo` class of `monaco.editor`.

As shown in the monaco-editor docs:

[image: monaco.editor documentation]

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/classes/monaco.editor.fontinfo.html

Upon looking into the Minimap component which uses `options.get(...)`:

[image: monaco-editor minimap component]

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f74e473238aca7b79c08be761d99a0232838ca4c/src/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/minimap/minimap.ts#L108

Is it possible to get this publically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, you have to use the `IEditor.getOption` function:

```
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "// ... some text content",
    language: "javascript",
});

// https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/monaco.d.ts#L3667
const EDITOR_OPTION_FONT_INFO = 34;

// Get the font info from options using the fontInfo option id
const fontInfo = editor.getOption(EDITOR_OPTION_FONT_INFO);

console.log(fontInfo) // Output: {zoomLevel: 0, fontFamily: "Roboto", fontWeight: "400", fontSize: 14, fontFeatureSettings: ""liga" off, "calt" off", …}
```